# How to change the color of TButton?

Tags: button, c++builder

In "Borland" C++ Builder 6, how to change color of button (`TButton`)?

I've tried in this way

```
button->Font->Color = clRed;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 11):

`TButton` is a thin wrapper around a standard Win32 `BUTTON` control, which gets its coloring from the OS, not the VCL.  You *cannot* set the `Color` for a standard `TButton`.  The `Color` property exists only because it is inherited from a base class.

That being said, the Win32 `BUTTON` does support a `BS_OWNERDRAW` style.  You can use `SetWindowLong()` to enable it, then subclass the button to handle the `WM_DRAWITEM` message so you can paint the button however you want.

Here is an example component that derives from `TButton` and implements `BS_OWNERDRAW` to expose working color properties: [TColorButton](http://delphi.about.com/od/vclwriteenhance/l/aa061104a.htm)

Comment: There is NO downloadable `TColorButton` source at the linked web-page: http://delphi.about.com/od/vclwriteenhance/l/aa061104a.htm

Answer (score 4):

Use TPanel, Set Color & Bevel(s) to match button appearance.
Use OnClick Event, voilà, it's Color Button ~;O-)

Comment: This is a good idea at first glance, but the panel will look nothing like the regular TButtons on the form, no matter what you do to bevel settings.

Comment: And, more importantly, it will require additional work to make it accessible using the keyboard (you know, tab keys, arrow keys, spacebar, enter, Alt+Letter, etc.) and accessibility tools.

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to use a `TBitBtn`, which is not a wrapper around a WIN32 control, but is fully drawn by the VCL.
Because it is a graphic control everything will draw as you'd expect.
`TBitBtn` even receives keyboard focus, so it should work.

Comment: Actually, TBitBtn does receive keyboard focus, so this is actually a solution to the problem.

Comment: @dummzeuch  Probably it's a confusion with TSpeedButton

Comment: I don't get it: what is the property of TBitBtn that allows us to change its color? I don't see a Color property.

Comment: @ServerOverflow, the BitBtn takes a bitmap. Create a bitmap with the color you want and stick that into the BitBtn. If you don't select one, the BitBtn if hardcoded to the system color for buttons. (clClrBtnFace)

Answer (score 2):

TBitBtn does work if you want to change the color of the font caption. The previous answer says it does not receive keyboard focus. I'm not sure what that person is meaning - but I just created a form with several other objects including one BitBtn - set my tab order, and indeed it will focus. I can hit the keyboard's space bar to push the button, and I can add an ALT-hotkey by putting an ampersand [&] in front of the desired letter. For all intents and purposes of a button, it seems to behave just like the Win32 control - but with CoLoR - yeah! And yes, I am using Borland C++ Builder 6.

- atomkey -